# Matching regex, Dealing with numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

So i am using javascript and i need to use regex to match some data with a mix of numbers and letters, but since i am learning regex at the moment this task is too complicated for me to understand and make it work like i want it, any ideas ?

> [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [**1113B86JD**] RANDOM
>   [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [**115M3X2G9**] RANDOM
>   [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [**1113P86JD**] RANDOM
>   [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [**314PTVPNL**] RANDOM
>   [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] **114PAVPNL** RANDOM

90% of the time the data i want is between two brackets length grater then 5 characters, so i found two regex's, And the rest of the data is still mix of numbers and letters but without the brackets.

1. > [(.*?)]

For getting the data between brackets

2. > ^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$

For getting the mix of numbers and letters

Now how to i combine both, i tried a bunch of times to make it work but it didnt work, can someone help me with this.

Comment: *"90% of the time the data i want is between two brackets"* Ok, so what's the 10% that you can't get? Or is that all you want is between the brackets?

Comment: It's difficult to answer like that, use [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/). It will help you create desired regex.

Comment: You want to remove `^` and `$`, because those anchor the pattern to the beginning and end of the input data, and that is not what you want here. And then you just put the brackets around that - where’s the problem with that? Show us what you tried, and with what results.

Comment: @zer00ne i edited my post thanks, the rest of the time its without brackets but still mix of numbers and letters

Comment: @Cyb3rHac3r I got a less complicated answer for you, if I guessed to what you require correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you seem to be after is any combination of 9 letters and numbers (no more, no less). I also think you want is to have the search continue after the first match. If so, you use the global flag `g`. See Snippet for details.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var str = '[ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [1113B86JD] RANDOM [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [115M3X2G9] RANDOM [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [1113P86JD] RANDOM [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] [314PTVPNL] RANDOM [ABC][122/29] [13:40] [RANDOM_TEXT] [PRT] [TPT] [RANDOM] 114PAVPNL RANDOM';


var res = str.match(/(\b\w{9}\b)/g);
/* \b word boundry 
|| \w Any word or number 
|| {9} 9 of \w
|| \b word boundry
*/
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hey this actually works great, I do have one question, is there any way to specify that the length to be grater then 5 characters instead of telling it the length is 9 exactly ?

Comment: Indeed  `{6, }`  note the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your letters-and-digits regex (i.e. the second one without `^` and `$` anchors) with special "compound brackets":

```
(?:^|\[|\s)((?:[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*)(?:$|\]|\s)
```

The opening "compound bracket" may be represented by start of text (`^`), an opening square bracket (`\[`) or a space (`\s`). Hence the `(?:^|\[|\s)` at the start of the regex.

The closing "compound bracket" may be represented by end of text (`$`), a closing square bracket (`\]`) or a space (`\s`). Hence the `(?:$|\]|\s)` at the end of the regex.

The letter and digit sequence you need is in the first capture group.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WLwu9p/1

Please note I made the group (`(...)`) from your second expression non-capturing (`(?:...)`) since in this particular case only grouping is required.

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked perfectly, and the explanation helped me understand how it all works